# Running linear regression on time-dependent paired observations

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data

I need to estimate a gravity model for my time dependent data. The data consists of 85 unique pairs of countries, estimating one dependent variable with 8 independent variables across 20 years.

I have already tried to estimate the data using a simple linear regression model, but this doesn't fit my needs.

```
lm(formula = FDIij ~ GDPi + GDPj + REXi + REXj + TRADECi + TRADECj, 
    data = Regression_Data)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-20874  -1465   -363    571  86448 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -9.231e+03  1.751e+03  -5.273 1.54e-07 ***
GDPi         7.942e-01  6.853e-02  11.589  < 2e-16 ***
GDPj         4.056e-01  1.345e-01   3.015 0.002612 ** 
REXi        -1.272e+01  6.568e+00  -1.937 0.052934 .  
REXj         1.050e+02  1.638e+01   6.411 1.92e-10 ***
TRADECi     -1.241e+05  1.957e+04  -6.344 2.94e-10 ***
TRADECj      1.415e+05  3.938e+04   3.594 0.000336 ***
```

I intend to achieve some beta for each time dependent factor, and some time independent constand beta. My desired models looks as follows:

```
FDI_ijt = alpha_ij + beta_0 + beta*GDP_it + beta*GDP_jt+ beta * REX_jt + beta*TRADE_it + beta*TRADE_jt + epsilon_ijt
```

Comment: What you labeled as GDPi in your database is what you refer to in your last paragraph as GDPit, correct? Same for REXi and TRADEi? If so, all you're missing is a categorical variable that's a combination of i and j. You can do this by creating a new variable by pasting the two country names, using as.factor, then add it to your regression.

Comment: You should look at the ``plm`` function for panel data. For gravity modelling, you can use a fixed effect for ``i``, ``j`` or ``ij``. So depending on your data, you will be able to specify ``model='within'`` (meaning, fixed effects) and ``effect='individual'`` (meaning, across your index ``i``, ``j`` or ``ij``).